# Sonar Coverage: file path in lcov coverage report isn't correct

Tags: angular, sonarqube, karma-coverage, lcov

Sonar build is failed in bamboo because of LCOV.info file path is wrong.
I have added script also in the Bamboo pipeline to find exact path for lcov.info and I am not getting any exact path in the log I am looking for.

what do I need to add in the sonar-properties file or karma.conf file?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to make sure a coverage report is generated for the test. So if you are running something like npm test from your script in bamboo, make sure you have --code-coverage added in your package.json.
2. In the sonar-project.properties file you need to set the path for where the file gets created.

```
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=enter/your/path/here/lcov.info
```

You can run the test local with coverage to see where the lcov.info file gets generated.